# Unrecognized element 'add' error when reading web.config

Tags: c#, .net, exception, web-config, custom-configuration

When I do this `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("SectionA/sectionD")` I receive this error:

> Unrecognized element 'add'

I'd like read all "add" element from this section to create a collection.

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="SectionA">
        <sectionGroup name="SectionB">
            <section name="sectionC" type="MyProject.SectionC,MyProject" />
            <section name="sectionD" type="MyProject.SectionD,MyProject" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <section name="sectionE" type="MyProject.SectionE,MyProject" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<SectionA>
    <SectionB>
        <sectionD>
            <add key="PerPage10" value="10" />
            <add key="PerPage30" value="30" />
            <add key="PerPage60" value="60" />
        </sectionD>
        <sectionC attribute3="10" />
    </SectionB>
    <sectionE attribute1="3" attribute2="5" />
</SectionA>
```

Comment: What is the code definition of `sectionD`?

Comment: Why are you not specifying sectionB in the query?

Comment: @MamtaDalal I tried but as receive a null

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of configuration element collection code delcaration:

```
private static ConfigurationProperty propIndicators = new ConfigurationProperty("indicators", typeof(ConfigurationElementCollection), null, ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsRequired | ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsDefaultCollection);

[ConfigurationProperty("indicators", IsRequired = true, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ReferencedConfigurationElementCollection), AddItemName = "add", ClearItemsName = "clear", RemoveItemName = "remove")]
public ConfigurationElementCollection Indicators
{
    get
    {
        return (ConfigurationElementCollection)this[propIndicators];
    }
    set
    {
        this[propIndicators] = value;
    }
}
```

So in config it looks as following:

```
<indicators>
    <add ... />
</indicators>
```

Comment: What is the content of ConfigurationElementCollection ?

Comment: @Kris-I: What is the definition of your SectionA, SectionB, SectionC? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991252/read-web-config-section-to-list/7991452#7991452

Comment: The problem is only SectionD, get all "add" value. I know the link but it's really really not clear for me. I'd like as result a collection with 10,30,60 ... a code welcome :)

Comment: Oh! You're the author of that question. Sorry, I thought you're just person asking a similar question :))

Comment: @Kris-I: An attribute of section SectionB?

Comment: Is it possible to add "<sectionC attribute3="10" />" in SectionD ? (same level than add) or place "attribute3="10" in SectionD as attribute ?

Comment: @Kris-I: You can declare add-action name, it can be "add", or "blah" or "sectionX". See [ConfigurationCollectionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationcollectionattribute.aspx) and its usage above

Comment: @Kris-I: It's possible, e.g. `<collection type=x foo=bar><add x=y t=d /></collection>`

Comment: In this page http://goo.gl/diVMf I don't my case :  an attribute in the section<sectionD myAttribute=25>
            <add key="PerPage10" value="10" />
            <add key="PerPage30" value="30" />
        </sectionD>

Comment: @Kris-I: Because you use `<add key="" value="" />` you need to mark SectionD with `[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(SectionD), AddItemName = "add", ...`, also it have property MyAttribute. SectionD is a collection containing elements with properties: Key, Name.

Comment: Pffff completely lost :( How get "MyAttribute" ? the "add" is in the section me I'd like read an attribute of the collection (sectiongroup)